# CSV Mapping coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use the following snippet of code: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/788/ to import a CSV.

I'm getting the following error:

> **coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found**

**Why?**

PS the file is loaded from S3 storage this is why I have the extra CSVImport to detect if its a string or file and should work.

Here is the full code:

**Runs the import:**

```
from core.csv_reader import CSV
            from .csvImport import CSVImport

            csv_object = CSV(self.filepath)
            this_file = csv_object.get_data()


            new_object = CSVImport(csvfile=this_file,
                                   model=Contact,
                                   modelspy=".",
                                   mappings="1=first_name,2=mobile")

            new_object.run()
```

**The CSVImport Class:**

```
import csv
from django.core.files.base import File


class CSV:
    def __init__(self, file=None):
        self.file = file
        if isinstance(file, str): # if the file is a string, it's a path that has to be opened
            with open(self.file, 'r') as f:
                self.data = [row for row in csv.reader(f)]
        elif isinstance(file, File): # if that's a file object, no need to open
            self.data = [row for row in csv.reader(file.read().splitlines())]
        else: # otherwise, I don't know what to do, so aaaaaaaargh!
            raise Exception("File object type unknown: %s %s" % (type(file), file,))

    def get_row_count(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def get_column_count(self):
        return len(self.data[0])

    def get_data(self, rows=1):
        return self.data


Error:

Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/contacts/upload/configurator/92/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'south',
 'userena',
 'social_auth',
 'djcelery',
 'storages',
 'endless_pagination',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'django_sagepay',
 'guardian',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'badger',
 'tastypie',
 'accounts',
 'contacts',
 'sms',
 'smartpages',
 'django_sagepay',
 'unsubscribe',
 'core',
 'django_nose',
 'debug_toolbar')
Installed Middleware:
('dogslow.WatchdogMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'async_messages.middleware.AsyncMiddleware',
 'core.middleware.ssl.SSLRedirect',
 'core.middleware.account.RefreshBalance',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test/contacts/views.py" in upload_configurator
  201.             process_upload_Temp(upload_id=upload.id, cleaned_data=data)
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test/contacts/views.py" in process_upload_Temp
  222.     upload.process(cleaned_data=cleaned_data)
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test/contacts/models.py" in process
  172.         new_object = CSVImport(csvfile=open(self.filepath).read(),

Exception Type: TypeError at /contacts/upload/configurator/92/
Exception Value: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FieldFile found
```

Comment: which line of your code throws that error?

Comment: new_object = CSVImport part of http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/788/

Comment: @Jingo update with error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.data` is a list (in `CSV`):

```
self.data = [row for row in csv.reader(f)]
self.data = [row for row in csv.reader(file.read().splitlines())]
```

hence `this_file` is a list:

```
this_file = csv_object.get_data()
```

So when you do `new_object = CSVImport(csvfile=this_file,...)` seems that `CSVImport` is expecting `csvfile` to be a string but you're passing it a `list`.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish but that seems to be the error.

Hope this helps!